# Windows7 - Outlook 2010 - .xnk error

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I'm trying to include a public calendar into Outlook 2010 on Windows 7.
To do this, I was supplied with a .xnk-file/link. The majority of the other users still uses Windows XP and Outlook 2003, for them, the .xnk-file is not an issue.

I have tried the steps outlined [here](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/xnk-extension-error-cannot-open-file/) but I get the following error:

`Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using`

I read [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeitproprevious/thread/45ce582a-6691-47b5-9255-81f5d9241afa/) that the `/x` switch is no longer supported in Outlook 2010.

Can anyone offer clues as to how to open the xnk-file/line with Outlook 2010 on Windows 7?

Comment: Just create XNK association per the article you linked to. It looks because of security reasons supports for the extension might have just been removed. If thats the case you don't have a great deal of options.  The procedure details for Office 2007 should work for Office 2010.

Comment: @Ramhound : Please clarify. I have followed all steps in the article I link to, without success, instead getting the error message. Should I omit the last steps editing the registry?

Comment: You have created the registry detailed in the article?  If after doing so, Outlook 2010 still will not accept the file extension, there isn't anything you can do.